# Prove the inequality:

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $A_i, A_2, ..., A_n$ be finite sets and let $A = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup...\cup A_n$. prove:

$$ |A| \leq\ \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i|-(n-1)|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap...\cap A_n| $$

Thanks for any tips/proof! Been struggling on this one for a while!

Comment: How about using exclusion-inclusion principle

Comment: Suppose you have an element $x \in A$. How many times do you count it on the left hand side? And at least how many times on the right hand side (separate the different cases)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$
A = A_1 \cup (A_2 - A_1) \cup (A_3 - (A_1 \cup A_2) \cup \cdots
$$
in which $A_1,\ A_2 - A_1,\ A_3 - (A_1 \cup A_2),\ \cdots\ $ are disjoint.
Therefore,
\begin{align}
A &= |A_1| + |A_2 - A_1| + |A_3 - (A_1 \cup A_2)| + \cdots \\
& \leq |A_1| + (|A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_2|) + (|A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|) + \cdots \\
& \leq |A_1| + (|A_2| - |A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n|) + (|A_3| - |A_1 \cap \cdots \cap A_n|) + \cdots \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| - (n-1)|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n|
\end{align}